# cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Tags: java, linux, spring, intellij-idea, mybatis

I am window from the project system to mobile Linux system when starting found error, the preliminary determination is caused due to the path.

this code

```
 <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:com/haothink/mapping/*.xml" />
```

the exception

```
Could not resolve resource location pattern [classpath:com/haothink/mapping/*.xml]: class path resource [com/haothink/mapping/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

who can tell me what should I do .

Comment: Are you developing this on Windows and running on Linux?

Comment: @DROY  yes,Has been developed on window

Comment: Could you provide more setting code from your project?